# Wake machine from hibernation remotely

Tags: power-management, hibernate, remote-access, wake-on-lan, logmein

Is there a way to wake a hibernating windows 7 machine remotely either via software or some other solution?

I use LogMeIn but have to also hibernate my machine every weekend but want to be able to wake it up and access it if necessary.

I understand LogMeIn can wake from sleep mode but that won't work for my situation.

Comment: as far as i know ..if its hibernated it is also turned off....so you cannot wake it up unless someone powers on the system....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your NIC needs to support the feature called [Wake on lan](http://windows7-issues.blogspot.ie/2011/03/wake-on-lan-wol-for-windows-7-made-easy.html), which causes the computer to power on from sleep when it receives a specially formatted magic packet.

This only works for wired ethernet adaptors, not wireless ones.

If your system supports IPMI, you can power it on using that mechanism as well. IPMI is generally only available on server systems, though, and not desktops